# Importing PHP variables from one scope level up

Tags: php

I want to `array_filter` an array inside a function:

```
function filter($array, $check){
    return array_filter($array,function($val){return $val==$check;});
}
```

Note: This is a simplified scenario.

This doesn't work, because `$check` is not defined in the filter function, but I can't use `global $check;` neither because it can't import variables from ONE level up. I also can't pass it as argument.

Any workarounds?

Comment: "I also can't pass it as argument" why???

Comment: cuz the filter function is internally called by `array_filter` but not the script itself.

Comment: declare it global. also, **you can** pass it as an arg

Comment: @Hiroto How to pass it as arg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `use` keyword:

```
function filter($array, $check) {
    return array_filter($array, function($value) use ($check) {
        return ($value == $check);
    });
}
```

It is essentially the same as using the `global` keyword when you want to bring an outside variable into a normal function. The reason you need to use the `use` keyword, instead of `global`, has to do with how [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) work. In short, they are turned into objects of the [Closure class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php).

Comment: equally as valid as mine, but fancier. ++.

Answer (score -1):

```
function filter($array, $check = $check_global){
    return array_filter($array,function($val){return $val == $check;});
}
```